# Flutrer Pub.dev data api

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I've been searching for a while about this but couldn't find any final words about it.
I want to get a feed of all packages from the Pub.dev site. i'm making an app to display all packages with examples on mobile.. all packages are copyrighted with their respected author off course. put can't find a data api and there's a .atom feed file but it only gets recent packages.
I could **scrape** the data but i don't know what are the legal terms to this. i tried looking at the terms of service but everything was too general to get a grasp on.
Can someone help?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pub Api is hosted here.

https://pub.dev/api/packages/

Example:

https://pub.dev/api/packages/device_preview

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial package for the pub.dev API. It's called [pub_api_client](https://pub.dev/packages/pub_api_client).